# Allocating memory for nested structure pointer

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct, nested

I am using a C code generator that is creating header files with following structures:

```
typdef struct Place {   
    struct Forest {
        int trees;
    } *Forest;
} Place ;
```

And using them in a c++ project.

When I try to access Place.Forest->trees, I get a segfault because Place.Forest is a dangling pointer.

I can't properly malloc it because 
`Place.Forest = malloc(sizeof(Place.Forest));` 
will just return the size of the pointer.

I can't use 
`Place.Forest=malloc(sizeof(struct Forest));` 
Because I am accessing Place from C++ and scoping prevents me from being able to see Forest.

How do I allocate memory for Forest without changing Place or un-nesting Forest?

Modifying the structures is impracticable due to the large amount of code that is being automatically generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of screwing around, I found a solution.

You have to use `extern C` to get the compiler to use C style linking, but you also have to use C++'s scope resolution `::` to correctly resolve the structure type.

header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typdef struct Place {   
    struct Forest {
        int trees;
    } *Forest;
} Place ;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
extern "C" {      
    static void allocateForest(Place *p){
        p->Forest = (struct Place::Forest *)malloc(sizeof(struct Place::Forest));
    }
}

int main(void){
    Place p;
    allocateForest(&p);
    p.Forest->trees = 1;
    std::cout << p.Forest->trees << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To allocate the memory for the `Forest` do like this.

```
 Place.Forest=malloc(sizeof(struct Forest));
```

It will allocate the memory as size of that structure.

Comment: Will this still work if the project I am accessing Place with is C++?  I though the scoping would interfere.

Comment: He's right, I get: `error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘main()::Forest’`

Comment: Sorry, I am not having any idea about `c++`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Place.Forest = malloc(sizeof(Place.Forest));
```

should be

```
Place.Forest = malloc(sizeof(struct Forest));
```

Because as you see `Forest` is a pointer to your structure and `sizeof(pointer)` is not what you look for what you want is `sizeof(struct Forest)`

Comment: Will this work if I am accessing Place from c++? I though scoping would interfere.

Comment: @charlesw If you have a malloc() definition then yes you will get memory allocated on heap for this call

Answer (score 0):

In C, nested `struct`s are visible through the whole program, so there's no point in nesting them. Just define them separately (and use `typedef`s so you don't have to write `struct x` every time:

```
typedef struct {
    int trees;
} Forest;

typedef struct {   
    Forest *forest;
} Place;
```

Now you can just write

```
malloc(sizeof(Forest));
```

Comment: Unfortunately modifying the structures isn't an option in my case.  They are automatically generated and there are several hundred of them.  Also,  if they have to be re-generated, the changes would have to be made by and again.

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate memory to pointers otherwise they are NULL. Use this :

```
Place.Forest = (struct Forest*) malloc(sizeof(struct Forest));
```

One another thing : Don't name variables the name as typedefs.